# Nested namelists in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran-namelist

`namelist` is a useful `fortran` construct to quickly initialize variables from a file. A `namelist` has a name and contains a set of variables with a known type. This makes it similar to the `type` construct.

It happens often that the parameters given to a program or subroutine are best organized not as lists, but rather as hierarchical structures, like the menu interface. Extended type like `type, extends(simple) :: advanced` seems to be a good representation of this hierarchical structure.

However, reading this data representation with the `namelist` construct seems to be awkward because one might end up with very long namelists of the kind

```
&options
 very_long_option_X   =  1,
 very_long_option_Y   =  2,
 long_option_B%long_descriptive_name_a = 10,
 long_option_B%long_descriptive_name_b = 20,
 long_option_D%long_suboption_DD%long_descriptive_name_a = 300,
 long_option_D%long_suboption_DD%long_descriptive_name_b = 400,
 long_option_D%long_suboption_DD%long_descriptive_name_c = 500,
/
```

Many people would say it is not ideal and they would rather prefer

```
&options
   very_long_option_X   =  1,
   very_long_option_Y   =  2,
   &long_option_B
      long_descriptive_name_a = 10,
      long_descriptive_name_b = 20
   /
   &long_option_D
      &long_suboption_DD
         long_descriptive_name_a = 300,
         long_descriptive_name_b = 400,
         long_descriptive_name_c = 500
      /
   /
/
```

Therefore, I would like to ask what is a good approach to read such data structures. How do you deal with this kind of situations?

Comment: If really necessary, I might use some TOML or JSON parser to read in such a nested input file, write out the data to a temporary namelist file (with % symbols) via some helper code or script, and then read in that auto-generated namelist file into a derived type in Fortran (via usual namelist), though a bit tedious way... (asking it in [fortran-lang](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/) etc might be useful for actual codes or other library-based approaches)

Comment: @roygvib Yes, to parse the second human readable form to the first one tedious namelist might be not so difficult. I would write it in fortran, but I am not fully aware of possible pitfalls. I will look at your link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuration files are really an area where custom languages or at least custom grammar parsers are often implemented. Not just by Fortran programmers, but also (or mainly) by programmers of many other languages.

Basically, one sketches a grammar which the configuration files should obey and then writes a parser for such a grammar either by hand, typically either as a recursive descent parser made of recursive functions consuming various elements of the grammar or as a state machine and defined transitions between the states. If one wants to avoid the manual route, one uses a parser generator (such as ANTLR) or parser combinators. These tools typically do not target Fortran. However, a search on github.com will reveal some recent [parser generators for Fortran](https://github.com/szaghi/FiNeR)!

Several years ago, when I needed a configuration file parser in Fortran, I went the manual recursive descent way. My humble attempt can be found in the `ParseTrees` module in https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/master/src/strings.f90 but it is far from perfect. I only show it for illustration. It reads config files like https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/master/examples/DIPLOS/area_sources.conf.

Libraries for universal formats like JSON can certainly be used (and there are Fortran implementations, such as https://github.com/jacobwilliams/json-fortran), but you have to follow their format specification. For example, JSON does not allow comments and that is a no-no for me.

Any advanced way you choose, you will be responsible for translating the data from the parsed syntax tree into your data structures. No tool can do it for you, AFAIAA. That is the aspect, in which the standard namelists really shine.

Comment: Nice analysis! I will look at the links you provide. I particularly agree with your last sentence. The advantages of namelists are undisputed and therefore I try not to deviate too much from this route.

Answer (score 3):

Since nested NAMELISTs do not exist, other approaches might be better. XML seems to be a popular choice. There are Fortran-XML libraries available, such as [XML-Fortran](http://xml-fortran.sourceforge.net/) and [FoX](http://homepages.see.leeds.ac.uk/%7Eearawa/FoX/).

Comment: Might be not easy to write a `namelist` to XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

What I do in my code is I would have an extra variable in the namelist that points to another file which then reads the contents. Thus:

```
&options
very_long_option_X   =  1,
very_long_option_Y   =  2,
long_option_B_filename = 'a_file'
long_option_D_filename = 'another_file'
/
```

Then in a_file:

```
&long_option_B

  long_descriptive_name_a = 10,
  long_descriptive_name_b = 20
/
```

another_file:

```
&long_option_D
  long_suboption_DD_filename = 'another_another_file'
/
```

etc

Then its just a case when reading each namelist in to see if the filenames got set and if so, read that file into the next namelist.